# Mvcsitemapprovider 4.0.1 not displaying routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm fairly new to asp.net. I've installed Mvcsitemapprovider version 3 without any problems but when I try to install version 4 it's not working.

The first thing I tried is to add the `XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` to the global file. Following the documentation it says to use `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web`. When I do this it returns that XmlSiteMapController doesn't exist in the current context. If I change it to use `MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc` it then works, however when going to the `sitemap.xml` it doesn't show any of the data from `Mvc.sitemap`, it only shows the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><url><loc>http://localhost:42370/</loc></url></urlset>
```

I'm not receiving any other errors that I can see. This happens on current and new projects and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to 4.0.2 and it's working now.